# How change key name API on Serverside ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to change key "_id"

```
{
    "_id": "5f3202ad5c79b21ee2d0d096",
    "pid": "5f31f3388743e88451e9563c",
}
```

to "id"

```
{
    "id": "5f3202ad5c79b21ee2d0d096",
    "pid": "5f31f3388743e88451e9563c",
}
```

And this my `GET` method

```
router.get('/person', async (req, res) => {
    const person = await Person.find();
    res.send(person);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just 2 you could destructure it and rename it

```
router.get("/person", async (req, res) => {
  const { id: _id, pid } = await Person.find();
  res.send({ id, pid });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just put it, and delete the old key

```js
router.get('/person', async (req, res) => { 
  const person = await Person.find(); 
  person.id = person._id;
  delete person._id;
  res.send(person);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Schema` it overwrites default method (to JSON) by a new one.

```
Schema.method('toJSON', function () {
    const {_id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
 });
```